# Calculating partial derivative function of multiple variables

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

For $ z=h(x,y) $, with $x=2s^2+3t$ and $y=2s-t^2$, I need to find $$ \frac{\partial^2z}{\partial s\partial t}$$

I know that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} = 4s$, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = 3$ $\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = 2$ $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = -2t$.

Now, $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial s\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ and I know that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=3h_1 (x,y)-2th_2 (x,y)$

But then, I get confused with the order of symbols for the following:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial s} (3h_1 (x,y)-2th_2 (x,y)) $$

Which order of subscripts should I take to differentiate with respect to s?

Is the following correct?

$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial s\partial t}= 3\left(h_{11}(x,y)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+h_{12}(x,y)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right)-2t\left(h_{12}(x,y)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+h_{22}(x,y)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of consistency:
$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial s\partial t}= 3\left(h_{11}(x,y)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+h_{12}(x,y)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right)-2t\left(h_{\color{red}{21}}(x,y)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+h_{22}(x,y)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right) $$

Otherwise it's correct, since $h_{12}=h_{21}$.

Comment: But why isn't it for the second term in the $3()$ $h_{21}$?

Comment: If you note $\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}=h_{1}$, then $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)=\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}=h_{12}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think I understand. It's all quite new and I'm having a hard time taking the right terms etc.

Comment: What do you mean with your last line $ h_{12}=h_{21} $?

Comment: I mean $\dfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y\partial x}$, i.e. the order in which you take the derivatives doesn't matter.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding that the order of taking derivatives doesn't matter. But you solved my question, so I 'm marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: See [Schwarz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem), a proof of which can be found [here](http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~mcwikel/h2m/SchwarzFxyFyx.pdf).